# pip script not running

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, pypi

**i use this command to uploade pypi pkg**

```
python2 setup.py sdist
python2 setup.py bdist_wheel
python2 -m twine upload dist/* --skip-exis
```

my pkg
https://pypi.org/project/abir/0.1/

**when I inatall pip install abir in install successfully but when i run abir it show me this error can any one help me to fix this problem**

```
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/abir: line 2: import: command not found
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/abir: line 3: from: command not found
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/abir: line 4: try:: command not found
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/abir: line 5: import: command not found
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/abir: line 6: except: command not found
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/abir: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `'pip2 install mechanize''
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/abir: line 7: `    os.system('pip2 install mechanize')'
```

Chek that pypi file and tell me the answer
**this script version is python2.7**

**My setup.py file**

```
import setuptools
with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()
setuptools.setup(
     name='abir',
     version='0.1',
     scripts=['abir'] ,
     author="ABIR HOSSAIN",
     author_email="abirhossain200019@gmail.com",
     description="this is a test file",
     long_description=long_description,
   long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
     url="https://github.com/ABIRHOSSAIN10/test",
     packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
     classifiers=[
         "Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7",
         "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
         "Operating System :: OS Independent",
     ],
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script `abir` doesn't start with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) so the command line shell assumes it's a shell script. Which is not hence these syntax errors.

To fix the script:

Add a shebang: insert

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

as the 1st line of the script.

Increase version; make it `0.1.1` or `0.2`.

Generate a new sdist and a new wheel packages.

Upload new packages to PyPI. Upgrade:

```
pip install -U abir
```

Test:

```
abir
```

Comment: Same problem https://pypi.org/project/abir/0.2/

Comment: You put shebang the second line. It must be the first. Before `coding:` directive.

Comment: I use  that and re upload but result is same

Comment: Nothing changed in version 0.3: shebang is still the second line. Please verify it yourself after the next release.

Comment: Check my code https://github.com/ABIRHOSSAIN10/test/tree/main

Comment: Script `abir` is not there. Most probably you've forgotten to add and commit it.